# Calculation of the distance to the next space station

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, programming-challenge

I've made a solution for [this problem](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1292&locale=en):

> **Task:**
>
> Write a program for calculation of the distance to the next space station.
>
> **Algorithm:**
>
> First base is located at the distance equal to
>   SMK from the beginning of the path (Sirius in our case). The next
>   station is located at the distance of F(SMK) from the first. Third
>   station — at the distance of F(F(SMK)) and so on. Here \$F\$ — is the Top
>   Secret Mars Function (TSMF).  Its value is the sum of the cubes of
>   digits its argument in decimal notation (for example \$F(12) = 1^3 + 2^3
> > = 9\$). So if the distance from the (\$I − 1\$)-th to \$I\$-th stations is \$X\$, then the distance between \$I\$-th and (\$I + 1\$)-th stations is \$F(X)\$. Your
>   cruiser is located between (\$N − 1\$)-th and \$N\$-th space stations at the
>   distance of \$L\$ from (\$N − 1\$)-th station. Taking \$N\$, \$K\$ (Secret Mars Key)
>   and \$L\$ as input your program should output the distance \$M\$ between your
>   cruiser and \$N\$-th station. Oh, by the way! The value of SMK is always
>   divisible by 3.
>
> **Input:**
>
> Number \$T\$ (\$2 ≤ T ≤ 33333\$) is placed in the first line of input — it is the number of tests for your program. It followed by the next \$T\$ lines.
>
> Each of these \$T\$ lines contains 3 integer numbers:
>
> \$N\$ (\$2 ≤ N ≤ 33333\$), \$K\$ (\$3 ≤ K ≤ 33333\$) and \$L\$ (\$L ≥ 1\$)
>
> **Output:**
>
> \$T\$ lines. \$I\$-th line contains the calculated value of \$M\$ for \$I\$-th test case.
>
> **It has to run in less than one second and take up less than 16 megabytes of memory.**
>
> **Sample:**
>
> http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/502/81219587.jpg

[Here](http://ideone.com/2kWEN) is the compiled code:

```
static void Main()
{         
    int T = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int k = 0; k < T; k++)
    {
        string[] split = (Console.ReadLine()).Split(new Char[] { ' ' });
        int N = Convert.ToInt32(split[0]);
        double K = 0;
        string Kst = split[1];
        double POST = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= Kst.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                int Kindex = int.Parse(Convert.ToString(Kst[j]));
                K = K + Kindex*Kindex*Kindex;
            }
           POST = K; 
            Kst = Convert.ToString(K);
            K = 0;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(POST - Convert.ToDouble(split[2]));
    }
}
```

But this code doesn't go through the time limit of 1.0 second.  How can I improve the speed of this solution?

Answer (score 13):

Here are a few tips:

- Instead of getting each character, creating a new string from it, and then parse the string into a number, just get the character and convert the character code into the number.
- Alternatively, parse the whole number once, then get the digits numerically using modulo.
- There are only ten digits, so you can easily set up an array of precalculated cube values.
- `K` is a double, but there are no floating point operations here. Use an `int`, or a `long` if needed.

Example:

```
int T = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[] cube = { 0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81 };
for (int k = 0; k < T; k++) {
  string[] split = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
  int N = Convert.ToInt32(split[0]);
  int Kst = Convert.ToInt32(split[1]);
  int K = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++) {
    K = 0;
    while (Kst > 0) {
      K += cube[Kst % 10];
      Kst /= 10;
    }
    Kst = K;
  }
  Console.WriteLine(K - Convert.ToInt32(split[2]));
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
static void Main()
{         
int T = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
for (int k = 0; k < T; k++)
```

That is a confusing of `k`, because `K` is used for something quite different. I suggest using `t` (of course for non contest code, you should have longer names.

```
{
    string[] split = (Console.ReadLine()).Split(new Char[] { ' ' });
    int N = Convert.ToInt32(split[0]);
    double K = 0;
    string Kst = split[1];
    double POST = 0;
```

Its odd that you decided to capitalize all the letters in this

```
    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= Kst.Length - 1; j++)
        {
            int Kindex = int.Parse(Convert.ToString(Kst[j]));
```

That's not a index, don't call it Kindex. As Guffa noted is not a great idea to convert between strings and integers all the time like that. It'll be a speed killer. Instead, I suggest using modulo and division to extract the digits

```
            K = K + Kindex*Kindex*Kindex;
        }
       POST = K; 
        Kst = Convert.ToString(K);
        K = 0;
```

Do this at the beginning of the loop, that makes more sense

```
    }
    Console.WriteLine(POST - Convert.ToDouble(split[2]));
```

I'd have done this conversion back at the beginning with the other conversions.
    }

```
}
```

As for your actual algorithm, I don't want to just give you the answer, because the point is to figure out. But, I can give you a hint. Print out the sequences of F(K), F(F(K)), etc for various K and see what happens.

Comment: Good hint. I'm glad I read it before answering and giving it away.